# Calculating Progress Bar Status based of shopping cart total

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, e-commerce

I'm looking to properly utilize a progress bar based off a users shopping cart. The threshold for free shipping is $75 so when the cart reaches $75+ the progress bar should be 100%. If the total is less than $75 the progress bar should show how much progress until it reaches $75. I've provided my code below.

I'm utilizing jQuery in my project.

```
<style>
p.shipping-msg-under {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 11px 0 15px 0;
    line-height: 17px;
  }

 p.shipping-msg-over {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 11px 0 15px 0;
    line-height: 17px;
  }
  .shipping-container {
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    padding: 5px 16px 5px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .shipping-price {
    font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
  }
  .progress-container {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    /* width: 39rem; */
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .progress {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #008157;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  /* Mobile */

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
      margin-left: 4%;
      width: 38rem;
    }

    p.shipping-msg-under,
    p.shipping-msg-over {
      margin-left: 4%;
    }
  }
```

```
<script>

let progressThreshold = setInterval(progressMsg, 5000);
  function progressMsg() {
    const shippingThreshold = 75.0;
    let cartValue = $('.order-total span').text().replace('$', '');
    let cartTotal = parseInt(cartValue); // changes the value to a number
    let cartDifference = shippingThreshold - cartTotal;
    let shippingMsgOver = $(
      '<p class="shipping-msg-over">Congrats! Enjoy Free Shipping on your order!</p>'
    );
    let shippingMsgUnder = $(
      '<p class="shipping-msg-under">You are <span class="shipping-price">$' +
        cartDifference +
        ' </span>away from Free Shipping!</p>'
    );

    // Progress Bar
    $('.order-summary').before(
      '<div class="shipping-container"><div class="progress-container"><div class="progress"></div></div></div>'
    );
    // Original Progress Bar Logic
    // $('.progress').css('width', (cartTotal / 100) * 135 + '%');
    let progressBarFull = $('.progress');
    progressBarFull.style.width = `${(cartTotal / shippingThreshold) * 100}%`
   

    // Content
    if (cartTotal >= shippingThreshold) {
      $('.progress-container').before(shippingMsgOver);
    } else {
      $('.progress-container').before(shippingMsgUnder);
    }

    // Remove Progress Bar

    if (cartTotal >= shippingThreshold) {
      //   $('.container').addClass('progress-remove');
      $('.container').remove();
    }
    clearInterval(progressThreshold);
  }

  // Reload the page to refresh the shipping threshold code

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    location.reload();
    //progressMsg();
    console.log('Page Reload');
  });
```

Comment: What is the question/what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You can cap the percentage at 100 by using Math.min():

```
progressBarFull.style.width = Math.min(((cartTotal / shippingThreshold) * 100), 100) + '%';
```